# Pegar no valor selecionado numa célula e subtrair com o valor da combobox em vba

Tags: vba

Boa tarde,

Tenho a célula seleccionada e agora quero pegar no valor dessa célula seleccionada e subtrair ao valor da combobox e depois pegar nesse resultado e coloca-lo na célula seleccionada.

Até agora fiz esta parte do código:

```
Private Sub Btn_Eliminar_Click()

Dim I As Long
Dim myvar As Integer
Dim comvar As Integer
Dim resultado As Integer



For I = 3 To Folha2.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
myvar = Range("C" & I).Value
comvar = Total_Stock.Value
resultado = myvar - comvar

Range("C" & I).Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = resultado

Next I

End Sub
```

Atribuí o valor da célula seleccionada à variável myvar e o valor da combobox à variável comvar e depois criei a variável resultado para obter o valor pretendido. Até aí tudo bem, mas depois ao colocar o valor na célula altera me o valor de várias células e não só da célula seleccionada, alguém me pode ajudar?

Neste momento sei qual é o problema, mas ainda não sei como o resolver. O problema é que não estou atribuir o valor da célula à variável myvar, esta variável está a 0, logo me dá o número negativo com o valor que atribuo à variável comvar.

Comment: Bom dia, já consegui resolver o problema. Obrigado por me terem tentado ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Você disse que "ao colocar o valor na célula altera me o valor de várias células e não só da célula seleccionada", correto?

Isso ocorre pois o trecho...

```
For I = 3 To Folha2.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    myvar = Range("C" & I).Value
    comvar = Total_Stock.Value
    resultado = myvar - comvar
    Range("C" & I).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = resultado
Next I
```

... realiza a operação de atribuir o valor calculado à todas as células na coluna C, da linha 3 até a última linha preenchida da coluna C.

---

Acredito que se alterar para:

```
For I = 3 To Folha2.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    myvar = Range("C" & I).Value
    comvar = Total_Stock.Value
    resultado = myvar - comvar
    Range("C" & I).Select
Next I
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = resultado
```

Somente a última célula selecionada será alterada, uma vez que o comando `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = resultado` só será executado ao final do loop.

Ressaltando que ao final do `for` a célula selecionada será a última célula preenchida da coluna C.

---

Ou então pode alterar para:

```
For I = 3 To Folha2.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    myvar = Range("C" & I).Value
    comvar = Total_Stock.Value
    resultado = myvar - comvar
Next I
Cells(i, 3).Value = resultado
```

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado por me tentar ajudar, mas no primeiro exemplo:

```
For I = 3 To Folha2.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    myvar = Range("C" & I).Value
    comvar = Total_Stock.Value
    resultado = myvar - comvar
    Range("C" & I).Select
Next I
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = resultado
```

ele em vez de retirar o valor na célula seleccionada, retira o valor na última célula com valor e eu quero que retire o valor é na célula seleccionada.

No segundo caso:

```
For I = 3 To Folha2.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    myvar = Range("C" & I).Value
    comvar = Total_Stock.Value
    resultado = myvar - comvar
Next I
Cells(i, 3).Value = resultado
```

Retira o valor da última célula com valor, mas mantém essa célula com o mesmo valor e escreve o resultado na célula abaixo dessa que está sem dados.

Estou mesmo com dificuldades em resolver este problema

Comment: Aparentemente você criou duas contas acidentalmente, caso queira mergea-las entre em contato através do link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

Eu agora fiz esta alteração, já me altera o valor na célula seleccionada, mas não me dá o resultado correto. Em vez de fazer a variàvel myvar(valor que está na célula) menos a variavel comvar (valor da combobox), ele está a substituir o valor da célula seleccionada pelo valor da segunda variável (comvar) e coloca o número negativo:

```
Private Sub Btn_Eliminar_Click()

Dim I As Long
Dim myvar As Integer
Dim comvar As Integer
Dim resultado As Integer



For I = 2 To Folha2.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
If CB_TipoFralda.Value = Folha1.Range("C" & I).Value Then
   Total_Stock.AddItem Folha1.Range("E" & I).Value

End If

Next I

For I = 2 To Folha2.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
If Me.CB_TipoFralda.Text = Folha2.Range("A" & I).Value Then
Folha2.Range("C" & I).Select

End If

Next I

myvar = Range("C" & I).Value
comvar = Total_Stock.Value
resultado = (myvar - comvar)

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = resultado

End Sub
```

Comment: Aparentemente você criou duas contas acidentalmente, caso queira mergea-las entre em contato através do link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact